# show format price rupiah (indonesia) in jquery from json

Tags: jquery, json

i'have data json:

```html
{"grand_total":"1.200.000"}
```

this json want to showing in `$("jumlah").val(data.grand_total);`

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Is jumlah an element? You should provide the type you are looking for. append jumlah with # for id attribute search or . for class search.

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Because I do not think jumlah is an element is it?

```
<div id="jumlah"></div>
<script>
var get = $.getJSON('https://someurl.to/json');
get.done(function(data){
  $('#jumlah').val(data.grand_total);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON to javascript object. That's how you do it:

```
var data=JSON.parse('{"grand_total":"1.200.000"}');
$("jumlah").val(data.grand_total);
```